# Add right click event VTK

Tags: mfc, vtk

I want to add radio buttons to a vtk window. I plan to add this by right clicking the vtk window and pop up a new window (MFC) where user can select diffrent data options. 
I could not find any example for achieving this. Please help me. 
I am using visual c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the OnRightButtonDown() function in your interactor https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/Interaction/MouseEvents/

Then you can do whatever you want (including popping up another window, etc)